# str_replace() not working for € sign

Tags: php

I want to get rid of the € sign here by using str_replace

```
$item['price'] = '200 €';
$item['price'] = str_replace('€', '', $item['price']);
```

So it should return '200' right?But it is still 200 €.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://codepad.org/NmP3pP2V), are you sure it is `€` and not just `&euro;`?

Comment: Also, your code will actually produce `"200 "` with a trailing whitespace, which is probably not intended.

Comment: aaaaah @kingkero was right :) it was &euro; I needed to clean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just filter the variable.

```
$item['price'] = filter_var($item['price'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

https://eval.in/214654

Comment: works :) but I also have to deal with prices like 199,99€ .. so they will be appear like 19999 :D which is way to expensive :p

Comment: @MarcSter Then use `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT` with `FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION` and only `str_replace(',', '.', ..)` - this is a way better/cleaner approach in my opinion. ([demo](http://codepad.org/nM87SDEb))